# google map marker display values when not null

Tags: javascript, html, api, maps

I have the var label and I only want to output it to the marker when it is not null. html is the output. How can I only show label in the output when it is not null?it works fine if there is a label field, but for all other markers, it returns null,becasue obviously there is no label for all of them.
Any help is appreciated

```
var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");

var html = "<b>"+name+"<\/b><p>"+address;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label") ? markers[i].getAttribute("label"):"your own label"
```

Comment: thank you for your response. figured out a solution that works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I didnt actually try them so i do not know if they would have solved or not. I am grateful for you help anyway though.

the solution was

var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label"); if(label == null){ label = ""; }

which worked for me!

Thanks again

Comment: var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label")==null ? "":markers[i].getAttribute("label")

Comment: sanket that worked like a champ. thank you, seems a little cleaner.